# How would you write this Clojure snippet in Ruby and/or Haskell?

Tags: ruby, haskell, clojure, language-comparisons

I was working on a Rails template and was trying to write a bit of code that allows me to populate a table or multiple columns of ul tags "top-to-bottom" and "left-to-right" across however many columns I specify. I'm just getting the hang of Ruby so I couldn't figure this out. I'm also curious about an idiomatic Haskell version for this useful snippet. Improvements to Clojure version appreciated:

```
(defn table [xs & {:keys [cols direction]
                   :or   {cols 1 direction 'right}}]
  (into []
        (condp = direction
          'down (let [c (count xs)
                      q (int (/ c cols))
                      n (if (> (mod c q) 0) (inc q) q)]
                  (apply map vector (partition n n (repeat nil) xs)))
          'right (map vec (partition cols cols (repeat nil) xs)))))
```

With this bit of code I can then do the following:

```
(table (range 10) :cols 3)
```

Printed out this would look like so:

```
0    1    2 
3    4    5 
6    7    8
9
```

And the trickier one:

```
(table (range 10) :cols 3 :direction 'down)
```

Looks like so:

```
0    4    8    
1    5    9    
2    6        
3    7
```

Comment: Three things you could maybe change on the clojure version
1. Use defnk (clojure.contrib.def) its a little nice to read.
2. keywords instead of symbols
3. instead of doing the converting to vectors two ways unify it with (vec (map vec (condp .....)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably write something like this in Haskell, using the `Data.List.Split` package from Hackage:

```
import Data.List       (intercalate, transpose)
import Data.List.Split (splitEvery)

data Direction = Horizontal | Vertical deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

table :: Direction -> Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
table Horizontal cols xs = splitEvery cols xs
table Vertical   cols xs = let (q,r) = length xs `divMod` cols
                               q'    = if r == 0 then q else q+1
                           in transpose $ table Horizontal q' xs

showTable :: Show a => [[a]] -> String
showTable = intercalate "\n" . map (intercalate "\t" . map show)

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ putStrLn [ showTable $ table Horizontal 3 [0..9]
                      , "---"
                      , showTable $ table Vertical   3 [0..9] ]
```

Some of this, like the `Direction` type and the `transpose` trick, was derived from jkramer's answer.  I wouldn't use keyword arguments for something like this in Haskell (it doesn't really have such things, but you can emulate them using records as in Edward Kmett's answer), but I put those arguments first because it's more useful with partial application (`defaultTable = table Horizontal 1`).  The `splitEvery` function just chunks a list into lists of the appropriate size; the rest of the code should be straightforward.  The `table` function returns a list of lists; to get a string, the `showTable` function inserts tabs and newlines.  (The `intercalate` function concatenates a list of lists, separating them with the given list.  It's analogous to Perl/Python/Ruby's `join`, only for lists instead of just strings.)

Answer (score 4):

I can't read the clojure code (I've never used the language), but based on the examples, here's how I'd do it in Ruby.

```
def table array, cols, direction
   if direction==:down
      if array.size%cols != 0
         array[(array.size/cols+1)*cols-1]=nil
         #putting nil in the last space in the array
         #also fills all of the spaces before it
      end
      newarray=array.each_slice(array.size/cols).to_a
      table newarray.transpose.flatten(1), cols, :across
   elsif direction==:across
      array.each_slice(cols) do |row|
         puts row.join("  ")
      end
   else
      raise ArgumentError
   end
end
```

Comment: Nice solution. It's cool to see variations on a practical problem in Ruby and Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something I quickly hacked in Haskell. I'm sure it's buggy and can be optimized, but it's something to start with:

```
import System.IO
import Data.List

data Direction = Horizontal | Vertical

main = do
    putStrLn $ table [1..9] 3 Horizontal
    putStrLn "---"
    putStrLn $ table [1..9] 3 Vertical


table xs ncol direction =
    case direction of
        Horizontal -> format (rows strings ncol)
        Vertical -> format (columns strings ncol)
    where
        format = intercalate "\n" . map (intercalate " ")

        strings = map show xs

        rows xs ncol =
            if length xs > ncol
                then take ncol xs : rows (drop ncol xs) ncol
                else [xs]

        columns xs = transpose . rows xs
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
---
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Comment: This doesn't give the right answer for non-square numbers of columns going vertically, though; instead of printing something that's `_` by `ncol`, it prints something that's `ncol` by `_` (`_` indicates "whatever number is necessary").  Generally, I think it could be tightened up; see my answer.

Comment: Ahh, I was looking for something like splitEvery, but didn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

My ruby solution

```
def table(values)
  elements = values[:elements]
  cols = values[:cols]
  rows = (elements.count / cols.to_f).ceil

  erg = []

  rows.times do |i|
    cols.times do |j|
      erg << elements[values[:direction] == 'down' ? i+(rows*j) : j+i*(rows-1)]
      if erg.length == cols
        yield erg
        erg = []
      end        
    end
  end
  yield erg
end
```

Usage and output:

```
table(:elements => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], :cols => 3) do |h,i,j|
  puts h.to_s << " " << i.to_s << " " << j.to_s
end

puts "---"

table(:elements => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], :cols => 3, :direction => "down") do |h,i,j|
  puts h.to_s << " " << i.to_s << " " << j.to_s
end

0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
9  
---
0 4 8
1 5 9
2 6 
3 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Slicing and zipping gives a straightforward Ruby solution:

```
 def table(range, cols, direction=:right)
   if direction == :right
     range.each_slice cols
   else
     columns = range.each_slice((range.to_a.length - 1) / cols + 1).to_a
     columns[0].zip *columns[1..-1]
   end
 end


 puts table(0..9, 3, :down).map { |line| line.join ' ' }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import Data.Array

stride :: Int -> Int -> Int
stride count cols = ceiling (fromIntegral count / fromIntegral cols)

type Direction = Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int

right :: Direction
right count cols x y = y * cols + x

down :: Direction
down count cols x y = x * stride count cols + y

data Options = Options { cols :: Int, direction :: Direction }

options :: Options
options = Options 1 right

table :: Options -> [a] -> Array (Int,Int) (Maybe a)
table (Options cols dir) xs
    = listArray newRange (map f (range newRange))
    where count = length xs
          rows = stride count cols
          newRange = ((0,0),(rows-1,cols-1))
          f (y, x) 
              | ix < count = Just (xs !! ix)
              | otherwise = Nothing
              where ix = dir count cols x y
```

This gives us a fairly idiomatic approximation of your original query complete with optional arguments:

```
*Main> table options { cols = 3 } [1..10]
listArray ((0,0),(3,2)) [Just 1, Just 2, Just 3
                        ,Just 4, Just 5, Just 6
                        ,Just 7, Just 8, Just 9
                        ,Just 10,Nothing,Nothing]

*Main> table options { direction = down, cols = 3 } [1..10]
listArray ((0,0),(3,2)) [Just 1,Just 5,Just 9
                        ,Just 2,Just 6,Just 10
                        ,Just 3,Just 7,Nothing
                        ,Just 4,Just 8,Nothing]
```

I left the intermediate results in array form as you had indicated that you them planned to format them as a table or ul tags.